# No createObject method in Component inside javascript

Tags: javascript, qml, createobject

I have inlined Component like

```
Component {
    id: movie_delegate
    MovieListItem {
        movie: movie
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to create new object like

`movie_delegate.createObject`

But there is no such method.
But if I do like this:

```
var comp = Qt.createComponent("MovieListItem.qml");
var o = comp.createObject(model);
```

Everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has gone when I've fixed other error, which is a little bit weird since they were unrelated, but may be I just don't see relation. Anyway question is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Do not inline the component, but use Qt.createQmlObject with a string.

e.g. (from http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qdeclarativedynamicobjects.html#creating-an-object-from-a-string-of-qml)

```
var newObject = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick 1.0; MovieListItem {movie: movie}', parentItem, "dynamicSnippet1");
```

Comment: I don't like this way of creating objects since I'm going to make a lot of them, and parsing qml each time is bad idea, with this way parent fields can't be accessed, no compile-time checking and stuff. Anyway I don't have this problem any more, when I solved other error this was fixed with it, which is a little bit weird.